# Vue.js. Error in the conditional rendering. Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Following code produces an error. I want to have a conditional rendering regarding to receiving event. I have a EventBus in the main.js

```
window.eventBus = new Vue({})
```

and somewhere in code:

```
window.eventBus.$emit('change-visibility', true)
```

I expect to trigger visibility of the next Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div v-if="viz.isVisible">
      <h2>VISIBLE</h2>
    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <h1>NOT VISIBLE</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  date() {
    return {
      viz: {
        isVisible: false 
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    const self = this;
    window.eventBus.$on('change-visibility', status => {
      console.log('RECEIVED EVENT', status)
      self.setVisability(status)
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    setVisability(ok) {
      console.log('SET VISABILITY-----------------', ok)
      this.viz.isVisible = ok
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "change-visibility": "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.viz.isVisible = ok')"

Comment: Which error is it? The one in your title or the one in your question?

Comment: Your definition of the data is wrong. You named the method `date()` instead of `data()`.

Comment: this.viz.isVisible is undefined in event handler (in method setVisability) and in v-if="viz.isVisible" also "property or method "viz" is undefined

Comment: Oh! Spelling mistake! Thank you a lot @cello ! You are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: The method returning the data should be named `data()`, but you named it `date()`.

Due to the wrong name, no data members are defined for the vue component, and thus `this.viz` is undefined, which is why the error message claims that `this.viz` being undefined is not an object, which it would have to be to have a member `isVisible`.